# nodejs ssh2 authentication failure

Tags: node.js, sftp, libssh2

I am trying to use ssh2 library of nodejs for getting the files from remote server. My code seems to work fine for a user "xyz". However the actual user will be of format "abc\xyz" where abc is the domain and xyz is the actual user. When I run the same code with the user as "abc\xyz" I keep getting the error:
"sftp error: { [ERROR All configured authentication methods failed] level: 'client-authentication' }"

I am able to the ssh manually using this user as "xyz\abc"@hostname, but for some reason this fails in the code. Am I missing something?

Due to certain restrictions can't provide the exact code here, but below is the relevant code after doing some necessary changes to mask the variables:

```
else {
  // Provide an SFTP interface remote files
var conn = new ssh2();
  conn.on('ready', function() {
   logger.info('sftp connection ready');
    conn.sftp(function(err, sftp) {
      if(err) throw err;
      refreshRemoteFiles(sftp);
    });
  }).on('error', function(err) {
     logger.info('some text +variable: '+variable value);
   logger.info('some text +variable'+variable value);
   logger.info('some text +variable'+varibale value);
    logger.info('some text: sftp error:', err);

  }).connect({
    host: hostname,
    port: 22,
    username: username,
    password: password
  //  debug: function(str) { logger.debug('sftp debug: %j', str); }
  });
}
```

Comment: Can you show some relevant code?

Comment: That's hard to follow. Code is difficult to format in comments, which aren't designed for lengthy content. Just edit your question and put the code there. Thanks!

Comment: and just to clarify it does pick up the value of username correctly (the logger part):
username is picked as abc\xyz. Also, I tried with different combinations like giving the username as "'abc\xyz'" so that actual username passed to sftp interface is 'abc\xyz'

Comment: Actually, let me re-phrase my question. Do we have some restriction on using "\" character in username in ssh2 library?

Comment: No, there are no artificial restrictions on usernames. Perhaps the OpenSSH client is authenticating with something other than the normal password authentication method (e.g. with a private key either locally from disk or from an ssh-agent instance, or with `keyboard-interactive`). You can probably find out which is the case by turning up debugging in the OpenSSH client.

Answer (score 0):

probably you forget to use double backslash in the username string to prevent of using backslash as escape special characters marker

Answer (score 0):

Hoping the following can give you some idea...
I read the ssh2 and ssh2streams api reference and worked things out with the following solution...

**Note** if you got any error like: *handle is not a buffer*. That probably means the file is not exist or you do not have permission to access it.

Let me know if you have any question :)

```
checkJobStatus(startPos: number, readBytes: number, callback: (error: any, result: any) => void)  {
    let conn = new Client();
    conn.on('ready', function() {
        console.log('Client :: ready');
        conn.sftp(function(err, sftp) {
            if (err) throw err;
            else {                        
                sftp.open("/absolute/path/to/file", "r", function(err, fd) {
                    //Define a buffer you want to send back to your parent method
                    let m_fileBuffer: Buffer = new Buffer(readBytes);
                    sftp.read(fd, m_fileBuffer, 0, readBytes, startPos, function(err, bytesRead, buffer: Buffer, position) {
                        if(err) sftp.close(fd, callback(err, undefined));
                        else sftp.close(fd, callback(undefined, m_fileBuffer));
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    }).connect ({
        host: 'server ip',
        port: 22,
        username: 'username',
        password: 'password'
    });
}
```